Can stardust give rise to new stars?
My question is if when a star dies, the material ejected (by supernovae or otherwise) can act as raw materials for the next generation of stars. If I understand correctly, stardust mostly consists of heavier elements, such as carbon, oxygen, and transition metals, and most stars are formed from clouds of molecular hydrogen and helium; thus, this should not be possible.
Would that imply that there would only be a finite amount of stars that form and die in the Universe?
Thanks in advance!

As place names are capitalized in English, the question (a good one) is discussing a "local universe" in a multiverse, which latter might contain an infinite number of stars.  An infinite number of stars might also be contained in such "single universe" cosmological models as Sir Roger Penrose's "Cyclic Conformal Cosmology", but its successive "aeons" require an additional (and hypothetical) particle (the erebon).

I asked a related question about how much metals would be needed to prohibit star formation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168437/25301 (unfortunately, I only got one good answer and a bunch of really bad answers, some of which are deleted)

Yes and things are looking so that about 10^12 years old Universe won't have stars any more.

The sun is a bit less than 2% elements heavier than helium, mostly carbon, oxygen, neon, and iron.  While the hydrogen and helium contents are largely primordial, the heavier elements (known as "metals" to astrophysicists) were essentially all produced by stellar fusion in earlier generations of stars.  The carbon, oxygen, and neon were formed by fusing three, four, and five helium nuclei, respectively; the iron is common because iron is the heaviest element that can be produced exothermically.  Heavier elements (including multiple nutrients in our bodies) are only produced in meaningful quantities in supernovae, making us, as Carl Sagan put it, "made of stardust."
The presence of metals in stellar composition actually does have a significant impact on star formation and internal thermodynamics.  The heavier elements, even present at only the 2% level, make the sun's ionized gas more opaque, since the rate of scattering of light by nuclei depends on $Z^{2}$.  That actually speeds up star formation somewhat,  since the higher opacity helps a collapsing proto-star trap heat more easily.

The sun won't go supernova though, so probably not the best star to use as a baseline.

Thank you for your reply! (And sorry for my late response).

About half of elements heavier than iron are not produced in supernovae. Star formation is speeded up because the gas is able to get rid of heat more efficiently. Trapping heat would have the opposite effect. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/what-is-the-origin-of-elements-heavier-than-iron
